# How to display the value of a table column based upon the values of another table column?

Tags: oracle-adf, jdeveloper

Jdev Version 11.1.1.7.1

My use case scenario is as follows :-

I have 2 tables as "Employee Details",which display the details of different employees and "Salary Details", which displays the salary details of each employee for different months. The second table will be populated based upon the row(ie Employee) selected in the first table.
The first table has got a column 'Total Salary', which will be initially Blank, and will be populated based upon the 'Salary' column of the second table after clicking on a button named "Estimate Salary".

Following is my code :-
Employee Details :-

```
  <af:table value="#{bindings.EmployeeView.collectionModel}" var="row"
                rows="#{bindings.EmployeeView.rangeSize}"

                fetchSize="#{bindings.EmployeeView.rangeSize}"
                rowBandingInterval="0"
                selectedRowKeys="#{bindings..EmployeeView.collectionModel.selectedRow}"
                selectionListener="#{bindings.EmployeeView.collectionModel.makeCurrent}"
                rowSelection="single" id="resId1"
                binding="#{backingBeanScope.backing_calculation.resId1}">

<af:column sortProperty="#{bindings.EmployeeView.hints.Name.name}"
                   sortable="true"
                   headerText="Employee Name"
                   id="resId1c1" width="230">
          <af:outputText value="#{row.Name}" id="ot17"/>
        </af:column>
<af:column sortProperty="#{bindings.EmployeeView.hints.Salary.name}"
                   sortable="true"
                   headerText="Total Salary"
                   id="resId1c5" noWrap="true" width="120">
          <af:outputText value="#{row.Salary}" id="ot1" visible="false">
            <af:convertNumber groupingUsed="false"
                              pattern="#{bindings.EmployeeView.hints.SalesVol.format}"/>
          </af:outputText>
        </af:column>
</af:table>

Salary Details :-

<af:table value="#{bindings.SalaryView.collectionModel}"
                    var="row"
                    rows="#{bindings.SalaryView.rangeSize}"

                    fetchSize="#{bindings.SalaryView.rangeSize}"
                    rowBandingInterval="0"
                    selectedRowKeys="#{bindings.SalaryView.collectionModel.selectedRow}"
                    selectionListener="#{bindings.SalaryView.collectionModel.makeCurrent}"
                    rowSelection="single" id="resId2"
                    binding="#{backingBeanScope.backing_calculation.resId2}"
                    partialTriggers="::resId1">

<af:column sortProperty="#{bindings.SalaryView.hints.Month.name}"
                       sortable="true"
                       headerText="#{bindings.SalaryView.hints.Month.label}"
                       id="resId2c1">
              <af:outputText value="#{row.Month}" id="ot26"/>
            </af:column>
<af:column sortProperty="#{bindings.SalaryView.hints.Salary.name}"
                       sortable="true" headerText="Salary"
                       id="resId2c5" width="195">
              <af:outputText value="#{row.Salary}" id="ot22">
                <af:convertNumber groupingUsed="false"
                                  pattern="#{bindings.SalaryView.hints.Salary.format}"/>
              </af:outputText>
            </af:column>
</af:table>

Estimate Salary:-
<af:commandButton text="Estimate Salary"
                      binding="#{backingBeanScope.backing_calculation.cb3}"
                      id="cb3"/>
```

Could anyone please assist me?

Answer (score 0):

You can write a managed bean method to calculate the total salary and set by accessing the ViewObjectIterator in the managed bean.

Some useful adf codes

http://biemond.blogspot.in/2009/03/some-handy-code-for-backing-beans-adf.html

Answer (score 0):

If your intention is to not populate the Total Salary column until the Estimate Salary button is clicked , you can add your calculation logic in the action listener of the button in managed bean. View Link from Employee to Salary will make sure when you pick a row in Employee, corresponding Salary records are displayed , more like a parent child relation. If you don't want the additional burden of a Estimate Salary button, you can add your logic in the setter method of Total Salary in RowImpl class which will do your consolidation logic of Salary records for a specific person (view link helps to restrict sum in context of a person alone).